# Can't Reinstall Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I just received my HP laptop with Windows 8 yesterday and I am learning the new Envy.

However, I observed that my WIFI goes down very frequently. (I checked on my other laptop which runs Windows 7 where I do not see any issue)

I am not sure if its just a setting issue or issue with my laptop itself.

Can someone help me what all the items I should be looking at to get this working myself?

Appreciate your time!

Comment: I dont think this as a BIOS problem.As you have the backup of all the data, wipe off all partitions and then try to re install windows xp.I suspect, the installation disk is corrupted.

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for your answer. I suspect the drive installation is corrupted but idk why any of the windows installation disks cant boot. Im using a genuine windows CD but its sp1 but i have sp3 installed. Cheers

Comment: Did you changed the boot priority in BIOS to boot from CD ROM?

Answer (score 0):

Woah, disk errors point to hard drive errors which could very well be physical. Crack open your case and see who manufactured the drive and obtain the proper diagnostic software to test the integrity.

Good thing you made backups and take note, Live cd's load themselves into memory so problems with the hard disk usually do not manifest themselves in the environment.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your suggestions. The installation may well be corrupted but i think the hard drive error is misleading as live cds report the hard drive as in 'perfect working order' . Further information. I cannot get any windows CD to boot at all and cannot get to the recovery console.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these things:

1. Boot priority set to boot from CD ROM
2. Your media, installation disk is not having any problems. I mean scratches or any damage
3. If you have a windows 7 or any other windows installation disk , try to boot from it also.